# node - async functions are not outputting

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Running v0.12.7

None of the default fs functions are running.

Example is `fs.readdir`

```
grunt.registerTask('commentTest', function (arg) {
    var fs = require('fs');

    console.log('Outside Test 1');
    console.warn('Outside Test 2');

    fs.readdir('./', function (err, files) {
        console.log('Inside Test 1');
        console.warn('Inside Test 2');
        colsole.log(files);
    });

});
```

So, if I run this, in the console I get

```
Outside Test 1
Outside Test 2
```

But nothing in the callback.

If I run...

```
grunt.registerTask('commentTest', function (arg) {
    var fs = require('fs');

    var files = fs.readdirSync('./');

    console.log(files);

});
```

I get what is expected from the job.

Something is breaking the async and I don't know what.  I've completely cleared out my grunt file and started from scratch, but I can't figure it out.

I'm looking at maybe a config issue?

Comment: "[Why doesn't my asynchronous task complete?](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete)"

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because Grunt is unaware of the asynchronous operation and will interrupt it, believing that the task has completed after `function (arg)` exits.

You'll have to inform Grunt that the task is asynchronous by calling `this.async()`, as well as when the task is `done` so it can proceed to the next.

```
grunt.registerTask('commentTest', function (arg) {
    // tell grunt this task is asynchronous
    var done = this.async();
    var fs = require('fs');

    console.log('Outside Test 1');
    console.warn('Outside Test 2');

    fs.readdir('./', function (err, files) {
        console.log('Inside Test 1');
        console.warn('Inside Test 2');
        colsole.log(files);

        // tell grunt when the task is actually done
        // also of the `err` if one occurred
        done(err ? false : null);
    });
});
```

Grunt documents this requirement in their page on [Creating Tasks](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks), under the heading "[Why doesn't my asynchronous task complete?](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete)"

Comment: Bummer this didn't come up in my google searching.  Thanks, though.